# Guess and Check algorithm dart language

Tags: dart

I want to learn `dart` programming language for mobile and web development. I tried to solve writing some algorithm in `dart` language, guess and check algorithm is very basic but I could not run it. Please help me.

Here is my code:

```
import 'dart:math';


void main() {
 int cube = 27;
 double epsilon = 0.1;
 double guess = 0.0;
 double increment = 0.01;
 int num_guess = 0;

 while ((pow(guess, 3).abs() - cube) >= epsilon) {
   guess += increment;
   num_guess++;
    print("num_guess =" + " " + num_guess.toString());
 }

if ((pow(guess, 3).abs() - cube) >= epsilon) {
   print("Failed on cube root of" +
      " " +
      cube.toString() +
      " " +
      guess.toString());
  } else {
    print(guess.toString() + " " + "is close to the cube " + 
  cube.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have your `.abs()` in the wrong place. I think you want `(pow(guess, 3) - cube).abs()` and not `(pow(guess, 3).abs() - cube)`